# Install ImageMagick for paperclip gem in windows

Tags: windows, upload, imagemagick, paperclip

I followed this guide to use paperclip http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip?language=en&view=asciicast
it is all ok but **note that to enable resizing you’ll need to have ImageMagick installed on your server.**

So how should i install ImageMagick ?? i have WINDOWS 8 and on the site http://www.imagemagick.org/ download does not work!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It certainly works - you need to make sure of 2 things:

- You install the correct **static** version for your OS (32-bit vs 64-bit).  The 32-bit (x86) will work regardless, the 64-bit (x64) will only work on a 64-bit system.  And you need to download the static version - not the `-dll` version - as Paperclip needs to call the executable directly.  (Of course, I'm sure that you knew that downloading the installer file isn't going to install it for you, right?  That is, you need to open the file to start the installation...)
- You add the bin directory to your environment path.  The installer should do this for you, unless you unchecked that option.

**UPDATE**

Just noticed that the links are broken :)  They still point to the older 6.8.5-6 version that have since been moved to legacy.  You can get the latest binaries from [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/).

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-6.8.5-6-Q16-x64-static.exe

is download from the site that does not work

Comment: @AlexFinocchiaro, you're right about that!  Updated with a working link - I wonder if they know about this...

Comment: i search and download here http://sourceforge.net/projects/imagemagick/files/latest/download?source=dlp after installation
i get this error

1 error prohibited this promotion from being saved:

Photo Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError

Comment: Try uninstalling and then install [this version](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-6.8.5-7-Q16-x64-static.exe).  Also, what type of file are you attaching - is it a standard image file (jpg, png, gif)?

Comment: always Photo Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError

Comment: When you run `identify C:\path\to\your\image` - in command console does that work?  If not, what about `identify --version`?

Comment: solution is specific folder  Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.5-Q16'  in development.rb