# Paperclip not saving image Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm trying to save image to db by using Paperclip, but attached image just isn't being saved to db. Am using windows.

Model class

```
has_attached_file :image, 
  :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
  :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",  
  :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

In controller :image is added to permit params.

html.erb

```
<%= form_for @product, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :image %><br />  
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Migration has been done and fields are in database but nothing is being saved.
Am using Paperclip 5.0.0 and Rails 4.2.6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install ImageMagick for paperclip gem in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655831/install-imagemagick-for-paperclip-gem-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem by not using paperclip and CarrierWave instead.