# Photo is not uploading through paperclip gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have used paperclip for the uploading photos. While saving data i am getting the following error

```
ERROR Original Error: ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed
```

Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install ImageMagick for paperclip gem in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655831/install-imagemagick-for-paperclip-gem-in-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```